# In Android Studio, app is running on emulator but not in physical device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android studio 3.4.1, In which my projects are not running in real device. but not having any problem in emulator.

After connecting the usb and i have run the app. then getting this error. after that device is not even listed in the available devices.

error got in logs:

```
Installation did not succeed.

The application could not be installed.

Installation failed due to: 'device '711KPMZ0603459' not found'

Retry
```

Retry also not working.

I also tried in Android studio Beta 1 and Beta 3. same problem happening.

can any one help me in this?

FYKI:
1. USB debugging enabled.

2. Tried USB option for File Transfer, USB tethering, No data transfer.
3. Tried with different cable as well.
4. Problem identified only after updating 3.4.1 android studio. Also facing in 3.5 Beta 1 and Beta 3.
5. Same kind of problem already added in Issue Tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122892907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill and Restart the adb manually through Terminal using below comments. use cd to go inside platform-tools under Android sdk folder.

> ./adb kill-server
>
> ./adb start-server

PS: Before posting this questing here, i already tried quitting the adb in Activity Monitor (which can be opened from spot light)

Answer (score 0):

Activate USB-Debugging in Developer Options and set your USB options from Charge phone to transmit Data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Device name is listed in the running devices. I have selected my device and started run. after that only getting this error.

USB-Debugging in Developer Options:  Enabled

Answer (score 0):

Well the mark of your phone is important because in my case i use LG G5 and i could not see my device even after turning on developer mode and enabling debugger options.
I don't know the type of phone you use but you can try my solution.
After turning on USB debugging, go to tethering under the networks sections and turn on USB tethering then try again.

Hope It helps!

Comment: Pixel 2 XL (now with Q Beta). Didn't have any problem with earlier version of android studio (3.4.1) and Pixel 2 XL. Tried USB tethering and File Transfer options along with USB debugging.